# Is it ok to create a form tag without an action attribute that contains several input elements without names

Tags: html, forms, validation

Is it ok to create a `form` tag without an `action` attribute that contains several `input` elements without `name`s?

I just want to use this `form` to validate `<input type="number">` controls' content.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's fine. The form will target page itself on submitting. But to get some data from the form you will still need name attributes on the particular inputs.

Comment: All `input` elements have `id`s

Comment: Well, it depends the kind of operation you are performing with your data. If  it's 100% JS validation and prorbably AJAX posting, so it may be fine not to have names. But if you will be looking to get the values with PHP, you will need them.

Comment: If you are questioning if it is a good or bad practice from HTML side, you may just check your code with HTML mockup validator